# Alphabetizing and grouping class objects within the source code

Tags: python

I’m working on listing a bunch of class objects for a new program. Is there a way where these can be alphabetized or over alphabetized within there own defined groups within the source code.

Like if I has a group of objects that were animals and some were on land animals and some where water animals. Could I automate where the land animals were grouped together then alphabetized and the water animals were alphabetized in my source code. I would also like to give the water animals the priority.

Like this

## this would be my list in source code—

Class Dog:
Class Cat:
Class Whale:
Class Dolphin:
————

## this would be the source code after automation—

The automation would then organize them in my source code as follows
Class Dolphin:
Class Whale:
Class Cat:
Class Dog:

```html
# system states

class xSystem:

class Off:

class On:

class Error:

class Update:

class Install:

# services

class Mail:

class Lab:

class Contact:
```

I would want services to take priority in this example. Outside of this example there will be multiple categories with different desired priorities. Like [system states, services, characters, properties] etc.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: opps I didn't qoute my code so it looked confusing, I think it's better now. My class doesn't have __init__ or attributes yet. I just want to automate the order first in the source code then start defining each class.